# how to get time from timestamp using carbon php

Tags: php, string, datetime, timestamp, php-carbon

I have a problem in extracting time from `$timestamp` which something looks like

this  `$timestamp = "2017-05-03 11:47:48";`

**my question is:**  how to extract time from above `$timestamp` like this `11:47 AM`

my current time zone is `Asia/Kolkata`

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you installed carbon, refer to https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon.

```
$timestamp = "2017-05-03 11:47:48";
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-05-03 11:47:48', 'Asia/Kolkata');
echo $date->format("H:i A");
```

Comment: i was trying this code but was not working then.  now it is working...!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all this

```
$timestamp = "2017-05-03 11:47:48";
```

is not `timestamp`, Its a date time value in some specific format. To change it to your required format you can try following code in Php:

```
echo date('H:i A', strtotime($timestamp));
```

here `H` is used for 24 Hour format, use `h` for 12 hours format.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you out.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785987)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$timestamp = "2017-05-03 11:47:48";
$dateObj=date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $dateObj->format("H:i A");
```

**Output:**
`11:47 AM`

Comment: is it possible to get 12 `hour` format from this timestamp `2017-05-03 23:47:48`

Comment: @EaB for that you can use `h` in  `H:i A`